# Get iframe content when it is on different domain

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I hv seen a couple of other related questions and I understand it does not work on cross sites. But I have one question. Can we make it work for different sites on a same company? For example, if the main page is on https://server1.mycompany.com and iframe is on https://server2.mycompany.com. As the top domain, i.e. mycompany.com, is same in both URls, should it work? If yes, how?

Thanks & regards,
Nadeem Ullah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. It's prevented by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).